# Ignore folders when packing a nuget package

Tags: nuget-package, nuspec

Considering a project in Visual Studio with the following structure

```
Project
---Folder A
----- CS Files
---Folder B
----- CS Files
---Folder C
----- CS Files
```

All works great but I want to pack only content from Folder A and C, ignoring totally all .cs files from Folder B.

is that possible?

I tried the `<file>` and `<contentFile>` arguments in a nuspec file but that doesn't quite work.

`<file>` only added them as a extra file in the package and `<contentFile>` had no effect

Answer (score 0):

How about this two lines

```
<file src="Folder A\*.cs" target="content\Folder A" />
<file src="Folder C\*.cs" target="content\Folder A" />
```

I had a similar problem and could use "exclude" to excluse all Tests.dll from my deployed dlls. But actually I do not know how to use it right to exclude the folder

Hope that helps